# jQuery cloned link not responding on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current solution looks basically like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="bar top-bar">
    <div class="barline">
        <a href="#" id="item1">Link 1</a>
        <a href="#" id="item2" class="btn dropdown">Link 2</a>
        <a href="#" id="item3">Link 3</a>
        <a href="#" id="item4">Link 4</a>
        <a href="#" id="item5">Link 5</a>
        <a href="#" id="item6">Link 6</a>
        <a href="#" id="item7">Link 7</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
var $default    = $('#item2').clone(true);
var $shared     = $('#item3').clone(true);
var $standard = $('#item4').clone(true);
var div = '<div class=\'dropdown-menu\'><span class=\'dropdown-box\'></span></div>';
$('.barline a#item2').remove();
$('.barline a#item3').remove();
$('.barline a#item4').remove();
$('.barline').find('a:nth-child(1)').after(div);
$('.dropdown-menu').prepend($default);
$('.dropdown-box').append($shared);
$('.dropdown-box').append($standard);

$(".barline").on("click", "#item2", function() {
 $(this).next('.dropdown-box').toggleClass('show');
});
```

Here is my Code: **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w65eq2q1/7/)**

Click event doesn't work.

Comment: Could you possibly add `html` too for this?

Comment: you should post a jsfiddle that includes your HTML

Comment: Preferably create a fiddle so we can check your code properly

Comment: You are binding click event to `.barline`, not `#copy_default`. Then you append `#copy_default` to `.dropdown-menu`. So if `.dropdown-menu` isn't descendant of `.barline`, the click event won't be fired. Of course, if you provide MCVE, it would be easier to help...

Comment: hi all @ I have set up my code on jsfiddle

Comment: Yes @ Goliadkin I have create jsfiddle. please check and let me know what i'm missing

Comment: **Correction**.  $(this) is actually the element you're clicking on.  Instead of doing .next() which is a sibling selector, just do $(this).toggleClass();

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the class 'barline' in your div-html. Or we need more code to answer the question.

**UPDATE:**
Actual your JS toggles the class but this class has no effect. 
Your css is missing a ".show" class, which set dropbox to display:block for example.

Comment: welcome to SO bro! although I don't think he even inlcuded his HTML yet...

Comment: I have update my question with jsfiddle. please check